# simple way of adding an weather API to an windows app

Tags: e-commerce, windows, weather-api

I am making an e-commerce app and I wanted to suggest season based products.how would i use the weather API to access the present location of the user and finding out the climate at that place and suggest him the products accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what programming language your using, but assuming it's C#, here's some code:

First of all, you're going to have to add these classes, which I generated with http://json2csharp.com/ :

```
public class Coord
{
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Rain rain { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can call the API from OpenWeatherMap.org, and use JSON.NET to deserialize it (You can find the package on Nuget) Please note that you're going to have to replace "YourAppID" with yours, which you can create here: http://openweathermap.org/appid

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
      using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString() + "&lon=" + Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString() + "&APPID=" + YourAppID)))
      {
            using (Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
            {
                      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                      {
                                 string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                 var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

                                 //Here, you write a ton of if statements, such as the following:
                                if(root.Main.temp > 32)
                                {
                                    //Suggest a large coat to the user
                                }
                      }
            }
      }
}
```